# unable to call a user defined function in sql query of sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server

Im unable to call a user defined function in an sql query of sql server.

my qyery is

```
SELECT Empnum(delimeter_test) as del FROM FNSPLIT_TEST WHERE Len(delimeter_test) >1
```

and my function is

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Empnum] (@RAWDATA NVARCHAR(300))
RETURNS VARCHAR(30)
AS
BEGIN 
DECLARE @TEMP1 NVARCHAR(300)
--DECLARE @TEMP2
IF(CHARINDEX('Disabled',@RAWDATA,1)) <> 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE SPLITTEXT CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT [item] FROM fnSplit(@RAWDATA,',')
--  SET @TEMP1=dbo.fnSplit(@RAWDATA,',')
    OPEN SPLITTEXT
    FETCH SPLITTEXT INTO @TEMP1
    CLOSE SPLITTEXT
    DEALLOCATE SPLITTEXT
--  INSERT INTO @EMPNUM1 SELECT @TEMP1
--  SET @TEMP1=dbo.fnSplit(@RAWDATA,',')
END
RETURN @TEMP1
END
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason **UDF's** require the schema name:

```
SELECT dbo.Empnum(delimeter_test) as del FROM FNSPLIT_TEST WHERE Len(delimeter_test) > 1
```

Also, here is a method of concatenating text strings without a cursor:

[Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)